# Prediction with RPART in R

Tags: r, model, predict, rpart

I've got a list of trainingsets (each with 944 instances) and a list of testsets (each with 188 instances). I want to make a model from my first trainingset and test it on my first testset. I've got the following code:

```
traindata <- data.frame(data[trainingset[[1]], 120:130],data2[trainingset[[1]],ncol(data2)])
testdata <- data.frame(data2[testset[[1]], 120:130])
RPART_model <- rpart(data2[trainingsets[[1]],ncol(data2)]~., data=traindata)
RPART_testpredictions <- predict(RPART_model, new=testdata, type ="vector")
```

But when I control my `RPART_testpredictions` with  `length(RPART_testpredictions)`, I become 944.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Spelling? `trainingset` != `trainingsets`. If that's not it, then you need to show the code that created `traininset` and `testset`.